# How to upload new version of application to apple store

Tags: ios, app-store, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

My application is on apple store (1.0.0) , i am ready with my new build to upload a new version 1.0.1 on apple store.

I am stuck in provisioning profile section .

Do i need to again download

```
1. Developer Profile
2. Distribution profile
```

I made both profiles 4 months back (for the uploaded version 1.0.0) ,one more thing- is the validity of application depends on that also ?

what is the difference bw uploading a new app and uploading its version ?

Thanks is advance :)

Comment: there is a dedicated app stores forum in stackexchange's area 51

Comment: can you kindly provide me the link for that ?

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores

Comment: thanks i ll search there for my sol :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to create a new developer profile or distribution profile. Make sure you validate it when archiving to make sure that apple is happy with your version number - you need to increment the build number otherwise this will fail also.

Just submit afterwards and the process is the same as the first time round. Good luck getting the update accepted!

Comment: how to increment the build number (are you talking about: Summary Tab --> Just below Bundle identifier VERSION i changes it to 1.0.1)??  and i signed my code with those profiles . do i need to make any changes ?

Comment: In that area bellow bundle identifier there are two boxes. Version and Build. I made a big change in my update so set my app version to 1.1 and then build to 1.1 also. For you i imagine you would put 1.0.1 in both boxes. It won't let you upload if these values are incorrect. Basically the build has to be equivalent to the version number or higher.